# Return list of values in conditional where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I'm trying to filter a table based on a parameter that determines which list of values are allowed for a certain column. For `@Parameter = 1` we want `MyColumn` to be either `FirstValue` or `SecondValue`; for `@Parameter = 2` we want `MyColumn` to be either `ThirdValue` or `FourthValue`; otherwise we want all values of `MyColumn`.

This syntax clearly does not work:

```
declare @Parameter int = 1; -- can also be 2 or 3

select * 
from dbo.MyTable 
where MyColumn in 
(
    case @Parameter
        when 1 then (N'FirstValue', N'SecondValue') 
        when 2 then (N'ThirdValue', N'FourthValue') 
        else (N'FirstValue', N'SecondValue', N'ThirdValue', N'FourthValue') 
    end
);
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Edit:** This works but is really clunky, so I would like to find a more elegant solution:

```
select * 
from dbo.MyTable 
    join 
    (
        values 
        (1, N'FirstValue'),
        (1, N'SecondValue'),
        (2, N'ThirdValue'),
        (2, N'FourthValue'),
        (3, N'FirstValue'),
        (3, N'SecondValue'),
        (3, N'ThirdValue'),
        (3, N'FourthValue')
    ) as temp(Option, Value)
    on MyTable.MyColumn = temp.Value
where temp.Option = @Parameter;
```

Comment: what should be in the result set?

Comment: About 10 columns from `MyTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this '*looks*' like a simple case of [Combining the AND and OR Conditions](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php)

```
Declare @Parameter int = 1
declare @MyTable table(id int, MyColumn nvarchar(100))
insert into @MyTable
values(1, N'FirstValue'), (1, N'SecondValue'), (2, N'ThirdValue'), (2, N'FourthValue'), (5, N'FifthValue')

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable
WHERE (
        @Parameter = 1
        AND (
            MyColumn = 'FirstValue'
            OR MyColumn = 'SecondValue'
            )
        )
    OR (
        @Parameter = 2
        AND (
            MyColumn = 'ThirdValue'
            OR MyColumn = 'FourthValue'
            )
        )
    OR (
        @Parameter <> 1
        AND @Parameter <> 2
        )
```

The equivalent using a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression would be

```
Declare @Parameter int = 3
declare @MyTable table(id int, MyColumn nvarchar(100))
insert into @MyTable
values(1, N'FirstValue'), (1, N'SecondValue'), (2, N'ThirdValue'), (2, N'FourthValue'), (5, N'FifthValue')

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable
WHERE 'Y' = CASE 
        WHEN @Parameter = 1
            AND MyColumn IN (
                N'FirstValue'
                ,N'SecondValue'
                )
            THEN 'Y'
        WHEN @Parameter = 2
            AND MyColumn IN (
                N'ThirdValue'
                ,N'FourthValue'
                )
            THEN 'Y'
        WHEN @Parameter NOT IN (
                1
                ,2
                )
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
        END
```

Comment: Your logic is correct so I think these will both work. I'll go with the first one since that looks more readable in my eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could work:

```
declare @values table(id int, value nvarchar(100))
insert into @values
values(1, N'FirstValue'), (1, N'SecondValue'), (2, N'ThirdValue'), (2, N'FourthValue')

select * 
from dbo.MyTable t
join @values v on t.MyColumn = v.value
                and (v.id = @Parameter or @Parameter not in (1,2))
```